# Sharing page on Facebook which requires cookie to be used

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cookies, share

I'm trying to allow people to share on Facebook links to pages which requires session cookie to be used.

The example of such a link is https://www.testportal.pl/?t=0MEWzYEHFUvc

As you can see on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object Facebook is not able to read this link.

My guess is that it doesn't work because during redirects the session is created for user, and without it, page cannot be accessed.

Does anybody has the same problem? Any ideas for solution?

Comment: Check if it is Facebook that does the request and don't force the user to login in that case

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, this is the solution which came to my mind as well. But can anybody confirm that FB doesn't use cookies indeed? Maybe the cause of the problem is something else.

Comment: Correct we don't use cookies